# Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C is a command no longer working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Visual Studio and Resharper 8.

For some reasons, my favorite shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> no longer works.

Indeed, the application shows in the status bar the message: `The key combination is(Ctrl K Ctrl C ) is not a command`.

Any ideas how to reset them?

Many thanks.

Comment: Reshareper overrides default VS shortcuts with its own. Youll have to learn to tweak the resharper settings or turn off its shortcuts

Comment: This might sound like a dumb suggestion, but have you tried closing and re-opening Studio? I occasionally have `CTRL+K, CTRL+C` and `CTRL+K, CTRL+D` cut out, and it's usually fixed by a VS restart.

Comment: @valverij yes I have reboteed retried etc...

Comment: Maybe the issue is that Visual Studio is expecting you to press ctrl+k and then ctrl+c. It's not either or.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very strange problem. Yes, it is possible to edit the command in Visual Studio. Select `Tools` and then `Options`. Once the window is shown, select the `Environment` option group and then `Keyboard`, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

There, you can edit the shortcuts:

- `Edit.CommentSelection` for commenting a selection (Default shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
- `Edit.FormatDocument` to format the document (Default shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

Comment: where do I  find options?

Comment: It's written in this answer, the one you commented on.

Answer (score 7):

I have had this issue off and on myself in different versions of VS (now VS 2017). I just figured out that it is a combination of two keys to comment and uncomment code in VS.
To comment code: Press Ctrl+K, then also press C while still holding the Ctrl key. 
To uncomment code: Press Ctrl+K, then also press U while still holding the Ctrl key. 
You can release the Ctrl key after pressing K, then press Ctrl+C (or Ctrl+U to uncomment), but is just easier to press the keys in succession.

I had never noticed the status bar at the bottom of the window stating it was waiting on the second key press (C or U).

Comment: The reason I landed on this question is because the solution you provided doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2019 here, not using Resharper - `CTRL + K, CTRL + C` "stopped working".

In my case, the solution was simple.

While editing your files, make sure that you are in the *Solution View*, not the *Folder View*.

[image]

Comment: Did not help me for .proto files (gRPC). But it still works for C# and XAML.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to resurrect a old thread like this but I have had issues with chording since this whole WFH/Covid-19 thing started.  When it first happened the only thing that worked was to reinstall VS 2019.  It happened again and this time I reset the keyboard setting back to default and it fixed it with out having to reinstall VS2019. It happened again today.  Resetting keyboard settings didn't work and I was not in the mood to re-install so I was living with it for a while.  It was after I took a lunch break that I noticed that a light on the top right of my keyboard, which is usually on, was off.  It's the light for scroll lock.  I hit the scroll lock key, the light came back on my keyboard and suddenly all my short cuts were back.

May not be the answer for everyone but if it's intermittent like mine was, it may be this ridiculous key that I have apparently never hit at work...

Answer (score 1):

I also has this issue and found this post, but then realised that ctrl-K wasn't working if code already has a comment within it, Not this is specifically when trying to make a comment in a razor view where there are html comment `<!-- -->` within the code that needs commenting. This is odd and the first time I have encounter this since the first version of VS.

The solution here is to delete or uncomment that code first.

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue with Resharper **enabled** just a few minutes ago in **VS2019**.

All I had to do was to reset the mappings. No restart required. (**Warning** : that will reset all your **manually** added mappings to its default values)

Tools --> Options

[image]

Comment: Are you still using vs2010 in 2021?

Comment: You are right, i forgot to mention that was in VS2019

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Format.

Follow the directions in the previous post - if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> already appears under Edit.FormatDocument, click on Remove and then define it again as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.  A warning will come up saying command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> was used to clear bookmarks.  This may be the root cause, as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is defined in multiple places by default.  Once I redefined it, it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Select **Tools** and then **Options**.Then select the **Environment** > **Keyboard**.

In the **Keyboard** section click **Reset**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'Ctrl+K' following with C for comment and U for uncomment while holding Ctrl works. However to simplify and unify the keyboard shortcut to what you are used to you can just change the mapping scheme to something else like VSCode:
'Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard'

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Be sure that you saved the file with .py extension. Otherwise, the software does not perceive the code as command lines and thus does not transfer the lines to comments